# Issues with setting up Xamarin with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

For the past three days I have been trying to get visual studio to work for Xamarin Development. It wouldn't work while my computer was on windows 8.1 and while trying to debug that I ended up damaging my OS and had to format/install windows 10. I am now on a completely new and fresh installation of windows 10 and the first thing I did was go to visual studio. Download enterprise 2017 and install only the Xamarin packages I would need to start development. When I create a new project I am unable to run it as it crashes with build errors. The android SDK will not open and neither will the ADK.

Someone please help me out, I have done ALL installation through visual studio there is no reason this thing should not be working.

Comment: Posting the error messages will help...

Comment: Do you get any error messages? Could you post the screenshot?

Comment: That's the thing. I am not getting error messages. When I run the SDK I see a cmd window and nothing. I have even tried running it through cmd to see if I can get an error and nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it will work for everyone, but I completely uninstalled avd and sdk manager (including deleting appdata and reg) and reinstalled it via android studio and it is now working. Maybe installing via Visual Studio has some issues right now, unsure.

Answer (score 0):

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/26234/visual-studio-not-responding-when-trying-to-config.html

or

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/24723/visual-studio-freezes-when-i-open-the-toolbox.html

Worked for me! hope it helps